# Move Text from Right to Left but Initiate the start from Left position

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say i have a Table width of 100 pixel, i want to marquee a Text from Right to Left but the start the text from 0 pixel position(left side).

But my below code starts from 100th pixel but moves from right to left.

```
    <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="3" direction="left" 
    onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    I am rolling from Left to Right
    </marquee>
```

I want the Text to start from Zeroth pixel position

Comment: Don't -ever- use <marquee>. Ever.

Comment: Not sure if you care or not but the marquee element is not valid according to the HTML or XHTML specifications. Plus it's about as charming as `<blink>`.

Comment: whats wrong of using jquery's animate() these days?

Comment: @j08691 : Then is there any Javascript replacement for that instead of Marquee? Any help link please ?

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, give your marquee a `text-indent:-100px;`

The -100px is the width of your marquee box.  This will start the text in the position you desire.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ldaf9/12/